How dotnet know where _Imports.razor is?
When creating Blazor project with dotnet new blazor _Imports.razor get created in Components directory. It's working fine.
I've server-side Blazor project "mutated" gradually from .NET Core 3.x to .NET 8 mostly by using upgrade-assistant command. _Imports.razor is in the root directory of project and it's also working fine. I want to try to "modernize" this project structure to something resembling dotnet new blazor template.
I tried moving even just _Imports.razor to Components directory (in Program.cs I've added using Project.Components;) but this operation breaks whole application horribly (a lot of unknown namespaces).
What further puzzles me is that I can move _Imports.razor to root directory in new Blazor project and it's still working fine. How this is possible? What determines where _Imports.razor can be and where not?

I trust this section could explain your concerns.   --> Every folder of an app can optionally contain a template file named _Imports.razor

We have a section which containing description like below:

Every folder of an app can optionally contain a template file named
_Imports.razor. The compiler includes the directives specified in the imports file in all of the Razor templates in the same folder and
recursively in all of its subfolders. Therefore, an _Imports.razor
file containing @layout DoctorWhoLayout ensures that all of the
components in a folder use the DoctorWhoLayout component. There's no
need to repeatedly add @layout DoctorWhoLayout to all of the Razor
components (.razor) within the folder and subfolders.

In other words, .net will check each folder to get the _Imports.razor in blazor project to make sure all the components in a folder could reuse the reference. I had a test in my side, which using a component defined in RCL in my main blazor server application. We know that it requires to write like <ComponentLibrary.Component1 /> or @using ComponentLibrary  <Component1 />.
If we put @using ComponentLibrary in the root _Imports.razor, we can still write <Component1 />. The same if we create a sub _Imports in Pages folder. But if I create another component which is put under the root folder, only the  configuration in root _Imports could make it work.

===========================
Deleting the root _Import.razor


Can you delete _Imports.razor from root directory? Is it possible?

I've read your answer and section once again and realized that deleting _Imports.razor would break application as _Imports.razor is applied recursively to components (that's also why my project went down). It should be probably possible to delete it after adding needed usings to components, though.

Definetely we can delete the root _Import.razor, but we have to put the @using clauses defined in _Import to each razor component which using the references.
